# How do i recover data without reformatting drive after USB to SATA conversion?

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, data-recovery, formatting, hard-drive-recovery

My External USB Hard Drive became unusable. Removed the enclosure and connected via SATA. Windows is failing to recognize without formatting.

What are my options to recover drive without losing data?

Comment: I'd say that the cause of the instability is the same reason windows thinks it needs formatting. check your disks SMART stats to make sure it is mechanically healthy. I use SpeedFan to read SMART data on windows. As for recovery, I'd start with Testdisk and see if the whole partition can be recovered. you will NEED another disk to restore to. there is absolutely NO way to recover data on the same drive, because it is likely to overwrite the very data you are trying to recover, rendering it gone forever.

Comment: Though it does not work often, freezing a HD as a last-ditch effort might help; see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/112050/recovering-data-from-a-damaged-hard-drive-the-freezer-trick. Whether it works (when it does) through changing alignment (by contraction) or reducing friction, it *has* enabled me to get data from a small HD (which was then trashed for parts... e.g. magnets).

Comment: @FrankThomas I checked the Smart Stats with HDTune Pro and it is saying that the hardrive is Healthy

Comment: ok, thats great! I'd try Testdisk first, since the whole partition is missing. you will need another disk with enough free space to whole the entire external disk. if you have a whole blank disk, you can just recover to it, but if not, you can attempt to recover the disk as an ISO file to a disk with free space, and then write the iso to the external disk. This is DANGEROUS in a way a spare blank drive isn't though, because you will be overwriting the source disk, and burning your bridge as it were. if the image you recovered doesn't work, then there will be no further options for recovery.